# Prove the following statement: If $n$ and $m$ are nonzero integers, then $n^2-m^2 ≠ 1$.

Tags: proof-verification

Here is my attempt.

Proof: By way of contradiction, suppose m and n are nonzero integers and that $n^2-m^2 = 1$. Then, $(n-m)(n+m)=1$.

That is where I get stuck, apparently we are supposed to show $(n-m)=(n+m)$ but I don't see how that would be true. Can anyone help?

Comment: $n-m$ and $n+m$ are two integers whose product is $1$. What integers have product $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(n-m)(n+m)=1 $$

$$\implies n- m=n+m=1 \implies (n,m)=(1,0) $$ $$ \;\color{red}{ \text{or}}\; $$$$n-m=n+m=-1 \implies (n,m)=(-1,0) $$
 Since, $n$ and $m$ are given to be non-zero, this leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes much more sense now.

Comment: @MANONMARS45 Welcome, *Martian!* XD